# unwanted empty cells on rows inside table with inline-block display

Tags: css, html, html-table, doctype

I have 2 tables that I want to display side by side. So I set the display style property as `display: inline-block`. The problem is, on both tables, the columns are not taking the full width of the table. There is/are unseen cell(s). Interestingly this does not happen if I remove the `DOCTYPE HTML` line from the top of the page. The red marked area in the screenshot is my concern.

I have tried setting the font size to 0 of the "tr" and then add my desired font size to the "td". Also tried adding negative right padding/margin, but could not get it to work. Please suggest!

Empty cells at the right of table:

[image: Empty cells at the right of table]

```
<table id="attn" style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid green">
        <tr>
            <td >
                Attn: Mr. HM. Mustafizur Rahaman
                <footer>Vice President</footer>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Attn: Mr. HM. Mustafizur Rahaman
                <footer>Vice President</footer>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>

<table id="register" style="display: inline-block; border: 1px solid blue">
        <caption id="cap_tab_1">Invoice<caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>No.</td>
                <td colspan="2">SSL/16/02011</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    Day
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    Month
                </td>
                <td style="width: 35%">
                    Year
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `display: inline-table`

Comment: @3rdthemagical: thanks much! that seems to work!! Up vote for your comment but I don't have the privilege yet!

Comment: I added answer for a question. If it was helpful can you mark it as useful?

Comment: @3rdthemagical : Thanks! I have marked your answer as accepted but don't know how to mark it as useful(?), I am not regular to stackoverflow and don't have enough reps yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem you can use `display: inline-table` instead of `display: inline-block`.

**Explanation:** `<table>` by default receives display property `display: table`. This is how it arranges rows/columns and determines how it'll be displayed on the page.

The moment you change that to `display: inline-block`, `<table>` looses its property to be a proper table according to CSS. So `<tr>` `<td>` etc. don't work as expected, as they shouldn't do inside a `display: inline-block` element. That's why `display: inline-table` solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

What about float instead of inline. Worked for me in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<table id="attn" style="float:left; border: 1px solid green">
    <tr>
        <td >
            Attn: Mr. HM. Mustafizur Rahaman
            <footer>Vice President</footer>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Attn: Mr. HM. Mustafizur Rahaman
            <footer>Vice President</footer>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="register" style="float:left; border: 1px solid blue">
    <caption id="cap_tab_1">Invoice<caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>No.</td>
            <td colspan="2">SSL/16/02011</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                Day
            </td>
            <td style="width: 40%">
                Month
            </td>
            <td style="width: 35%">
                Year
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was looking for a solution to work with the tables.